# Rspec throwing undefined local variable on url path in view, but actual view reads it fine

Tags: rspec, actionmailer

When I run bundle exec rspec spec/, I get the following error:

```
`_app_views_demo_mailer_new_user_text_haml___514868986949697059_2155319320_502394691365870694': undefined local variable or method `courses_url' for #<#<Class:0x00000100eee3e0>:0x00000100eeb3c0> (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

The relevant view section is:

```
If you haven't already signed up for a course, you can do so here:
= courses_url
```

The view in question is a .text.haml mailer. The odd thing is, the actual mailer reads the 'courses_url' just fine. Rake routes confirms it's there...but rspec throws that error, and I'm stumped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question and add the spec code...BTW, I had a similar problem and the error was I missed to call `it` (I used `describe` instead of `it`) and I got this strange error.